# adding an element within an appended element

Tags: javascript

I am just working on my first ever project with Javascript, a todo list. With every list element that gets appended, I would also like to include a span element within it, which will represent a check icon to cofirm the task has been completed. However, I'm not too sure how to go about this. Please can someone help.

Check out the code. This is what I have so far. Only the list element and value entereted by the user will appear with this code.

```
document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", function(){
                       var taskinput = document.getElementById("task").value;
                        if (taskinput) 
                        {
                              var tasktext = document.createTextNode(taskinput);
                              var list = document.createElement("li");
                              list.appendChild(tasktext);
                              document.getElementById("task-to-do").appendChild(list);
                              document.getElementById("task").value ="";
                        } else 
                        {
                              alert("Please enter a task");
                        }
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you right you just want to append `span` to each `li`, right? So do it the same way as you do with `tasktext`

```
var span = document.createElement("span");
//do whatever you want with `span` the same way as you would with `li`

list.appendChild(span);
```

Basically it works like play with blocks. You want it to look like this:

```
<li>"Some text"<span></span></li>
```

So here you have three blocks: `li`, `textNode` and `span`. Now play with it. Create `li` block. Then "sculp" it- set desired attributes. Then create another one- `textNode`. Give it some value etc. Now create another one- `span`. Again "sculp" it- set some attributes and other stuff.
Now when you have your blocks ready, it's time to join them in any way you wish. In your case it'll be:
Take `textNode` and put it into `li`. Now take `span` and put it into `li`.

And that's pretty much all. Not so hard, isn't it? :)

Comment: correct, so basically the html would look like this <ul><li>"user input here"<span></span></li>

Comment: So this is your solution. After you add `tasktext` just add `span` and your element will look like you mentioned

Comment: Thank you very much Sebastian! :)